# Removin /page/2 from pagination

Tags: categories, pagination, paginate-links

I would like to remove `/page` from category pagination or translate is so it looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/category/catname/2
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/category/catname/customword/2
```

Couldn't find anything while googleing. Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Plugin recommendation is not on topic here :( can you rephrase your question and add some of the things you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you would like to edit the url for your posts/pages. If you login to your dashboard as an admin user, you can navigate to settings/Permalinks and choose a pre-made option for you or create a custom one